# How can i change the background image of a list item

Tags: jquery, html, css, mouseover

I want to change my `<Li>` bgImage onMouseOver using jQuery

But image is in three div tags

Comment: The question is not really clear, can you please give an example html and javascript ?

Answer (score 5):

Something like this:

```
$('li').mouseover(
  function(){
    $(this).css('background-image', 'url(hover.png) no-repeat top left');
  },
  function(){
    $(this).css('background-image', 'url(normal.png) no-repeat top left');
  }
);
```

Comment: @quark: don't you mean $('li').hover in your example? I don't think the .mouseover event takes two callbacks..

Comment: First function is triggered when the mouse pointer moves into a <li> element and sets the hover image.

Second one is triggered when mouse leaves <li> element and reverts image to normal state.

If you use .hover() then you'll not be able to change image back.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to know why you need to change the background image of a list item on mouse over.

If you want that the list item act like a link - or, in general, **if you want assign an action to the list item** -  you should add an `<a>` tag inside the `<li>`, and use the **a:hover** css selector to assign the background image of the link on mouse over. In this way you don't need any javascript function.

If you can't use an `<a>` tag I would like to know why.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding/removing a background image with CSS, you should add/remove class on hover. This way you can compress your JS file when you release it in the wild :)

However, i guess he wants to save current background image, replace it on mouse over and revert it back on mouse out :)